# Error while trying to access Google translate with NSURL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurl, google-translate

If I try this code:

```
NSError *err = nil;
NSString *resp = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=abdicate&langpair=en|es"]
                                          encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding 
                                             error:&err];
```

Err contains the following message: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=258 UserInfo=0x1001166d0 "The file name is invalid."

Anybody knows what this means? If I try the url on a browser, it works fine.

Comment: Try `NSData` replace the `1.0` with `1%2E0` and the `|` with `%7C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Using `NSData`) you can just replace the `1.0` with `1%2E0` and the `|` with `%7C`.  It is possible that with the period is being interpreted as a file with an extension, thus the 258 error ([From Foundation Constants Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html)):

> NSError Codes
>
> NSError codes in the Cocoa error domain.

```
enum {
   ...
   NSFileReadInvalidFileNameError = 258,
}
```

> NSFileReadInvalidFileNameError:
>   Read error because of an invalid file
>   name Available in Mac OS X v10.4 and later. Declared in
>   FoundationErrors.h.

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1%2E0&q=abdicate&langpair=en%7Ces"]];
    if (data) {
        NSLog([[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
    }
}
```

Gives the output:

```
2011-09-27 15:38:05.691 Project[44290:fb03] {"responseData": {"translatedText":"abdicar"}, "responseDetails": null, "responseStatus": 200}
```

Which is the same as what you get by navigating to the url https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=abdicate&langpair=en|es in a browser.

---

<strike>Try using NSData, then converting to a string, like so:</strike>

```
NSString *result;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?%@", [self urlencode:@"v=1.0&q=abdicate&langpair=en|es"]]]];
    if (data) {
       result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    } else {
        // Do something
    }
```

This is the urlencode method used above:

```
- (NSString *)urlencode:(NSString *)str {
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString string];
    const unsigned char *source = (const unsigned char *)[str UTF8String];
    int sourceLen = strlen((const char *)source);
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceLen; ++i) {
        const unsigned char thisChar = source[i];
        if (thisChar == ' '){
            [output appendString:@"+"];
        } else if (thisChar == '.' || thisChar == '-' || thisChar == '_' || thisChar == '~' || 
                   (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') ||
                   (thisChar >= 'A' && thisChar <= 'Z') ||
                   (thisChar >= '0' && thisChar <= '9')) {
            [output appendFormat:@"%c", thisChar];
        } else {
            [output appendFormat:@"%%%02X", thisChar];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

This whole part was unnecessary, just need to replace the 1.0 and | instead of encoding the entire url.

Comment: Just read up on [RFC 2396](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396#appendix-A) that only the `|` should need to be escaped, not the `.`, so it does look like it could be a bug.

Comment: . is not being replaced in the code above, but space should be @"\%20" because a + in the query is a reserved character. Also, note that the URL has `Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8` so it should be NSUTF8StringEncoding instead NSASCIIStringEncoding.