# Cocoa error 256, When using initWithContentsOfURL:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

i getting data from my site:

```
NSString *website = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/fbconnect.php?email=%@&name=%@&pass=***", nameTrimmmed, [jsonObject objectForKey:@"email"]];
NSLog(@"%@", website);
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *contents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:website] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

contents have Cocoa error 256. where i wrong?

Comment: You seem to mixup email and name in your parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in Hebrew characters, you should html-escape them, also try request with English characters instead, to see if it works

```
- (void)yourMethod
{
    NSString *name = @"שימרגוליס";
    name = AFURLEncodedStringFromStringWithEncoding(name, NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    NSString *website = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.ba-cafe.com/fbconnect.php?email=%@&name=%@&pass=SwHyK17!",@"email@mail.com",name];
    NSLog(@"%@", website);
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *contents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:website] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
}
```

Where `AFURLEncodedStringFromStringWithEncoding`is a function from [AFNetworking framework](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m)

Comment: as I said you escape them locally and unescape on the serverside, a good example of escape function for objective-c can be found in AFNetworking code https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m#L95
  
So you string would look like `%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A1` which is completely valid for URL

Comment: CF stands for Core Foundation and `CFStringRef` for example is underlying class representing `NSString`. In case you use ARC and you want just to copy method from AFNetwroking, see updated answer for the code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15565/discussion-between-theshay-and-alexander-zats)

Comment: do you use ARC? if no then just use function code from the link above as is

Answer (score 0):

Check the Console log for `NSLog(@"%@", website);`

You will see something like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/fbconnect.php?email=thetrimmedname&name=emailaddress&pass=***
```

So do this:

```
NSString *website = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/fbconnect.php?email=%@&name=%@&pass=***", [jsonObject objectForKey:@"email"], nameTrimmmed ];
```

instead of this:

```
NSString *website = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/fbconnect.php?email=%@&name=%@&pass=***", nameTrimmmed, [jsonObject objectForKey:@"email"]];
```

Comment: again, change position not helped.

Comment: Then you need to have a visit here: http://blog.beefyapps.com/2010/03/coredata-sqlite3-database-constraint-failed-error/

Comment: so i need to change my mysql table?

Comment: No, the error is similar to yours, the article will help you understand why you're getting this error.

Comment: so i dont understand this. the error is in my server or on the iphone?

Comment: Are you storing this data somewhere your app?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15561/discussion-between-theshay-and-ohhmee)

Answer (score -1):

This is because of the dot in the email address.

Look right here:
[Error while trying to access Google translate with NSURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576103/error-while-trying-to-access-google-translate-with-nsurl)

Comment: not working. the URL working on the browser not on the iphone.